# How to prevent notificationBar being masked in a layout PrimeFaces 5.1?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Hi community I have a problem with notificationBar component is hidden due to an absolute position that will add to my menu this the right.

[image]

As noticed the notificationBar, shown below the left menu layout that contains my, what happens is that I had to add style position abosolute my menu for the menu is displayed in the center of the layout.

```
.ui-layout-west {
    z-index: 20 !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}

.ui-layout-west .ui-layout-unit-content {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

My component p: notificationBar

```
<p:notificationBar position="top" effect="slide" widgetVar="barMensajes" >
        <h:outputText value="Mensajes del Sistema:" styleClass="clsEncabezadoPantalla" />
        <p:messages id="messagesPrincipalForm" showDetail="true" globalOnly="true" closable="true" escape="false" />
        <p:commandButton value="Hide" onclick="PF('barMensajes').hide()"
                         type="button" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-n" />
    </p:notificationBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello friend and found the solution to my problem, now I only need to see that the attribute does not work: background-color: white! important;

```
.ui-notificationbar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F8F7F6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0A2967;
    opacity: 0.95;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 95); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    z-index: 999; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Best to post new questions in.... a new question... But try to see if there also is a background-image and if so, set that to 'none'...

Comment: and you can 'accept' your own answer... Then this question is at least 'marked' it has an answer